# c - segmentation fault assigning to 2d array

Tags: c, dynamic, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, allocation

I'm trying to take a bmp file and make a grayscale copy. I'm learning about dynamic allocation and I have to dynamically allocate a 2D array which I import the bmp file to and manipulate it from, so it will work with various picture sizes. But near the end (I labeled where) I get a Seg Fault and I have no idea why. Everything works great if I don't dynamically allocate "pixels".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     

int main(void) {

    const int HEADER_SIZE = 54;

    FILE *infile = fopen("test1.bmp", "rb"); 
    FILE *outfile1 = fopen("copy1.bmp", "wb");

    int i, width, height, r, c, bmpsize;
    char header[HEADER_SIZE], filename[32];
    char **pixels;                                //initialize pixels here

    puts("Enter the filename: ");

    i = -1;
    while(filename[i] != '\n')
    {
         i++;
         scanf("%c", &filename[i]);
    }
    filename[i] = '.';
    filename[i+1] = 'b';
    filename[i+2] = 'm';
    filename[i+3] = 'p';
    filename[i+4] = '\0';

    i = -1;
    while(filename[i] != '\0')
    {
         i++;
         printf("%c", filename[i]);
    }

    infile = fopen(filename, "rb");

    puts("Enter the height and width (in pixels): ");
    scanf("%d%d", &height, &width);

    bmpsize = 3 * width * height;

    pixels =  malloc(height * sizeof(char*));            //DA part 1

    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] = malloc((width * 3) * sizeof(char));  //DA part 2
    }

    fread(header, 1 , HEADER_SIZE, infile);
    fread(pixels, 1 , bmpsize, infile);

    for( r = 0; r < height; r++) {
         for ( c = 0; c < width*3; c += 3) {
             int avg= 0;
             puts("THIS PUTS PRINTS: THE NEXT LINE IS MY PROBLEM");
             avg = ((int) pixels[r][c] + (int) pixels[r][c+1] + (int) pixels[r][c+2]) / 3;//This is my problem line, why?
             puts("THIS PUTS DOESN'T PRINT. ERROR: SEG. FAULT(core dumped)");
             pixels[r][c] = (char) avg;
             pixels[r][c+1] = (char) avg;
             pixels[r][c+2] = (char) avg;
         }
    }

    puts("Done. Check the generated images.");

    fwrite(header, sizeof(char)  , HEADER_SIZE,  outfile1);
    fwrite(pixels, sizeof(char)  , bmpsize,  outfile1);

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best to add the C tag for a C question

Comment: whatever the problem is, you should still check that you're not getting NULL pointers returned by malloc. Dereferencing a NULL pointer will also give you a segfault.

Comment: Do `char (*pixels)[width*3] = malloc( width * height * 3 );` , then you can use `pixels[r][c]` and also `fread`. BTW check return value of `fread` and `malloc`.

Comment: Figured it out. it was the fread(). I wasn't allocating a contiguous memory block that way, I needed to simulate a 2D array within a 1D array, so it would be contiguous for fread. Problem solved. thanks people who answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `fread` call and how you are setting up the input buffer for the file contents

```
pixels =  malloc(height * sizeof(char*));            //DA part 1

for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = malloc((width * 3) * sizeof(char));  //DA part 2
}

fread(pixels, 1 , bmpsize, infile);
```

The memory you have allocated **in total** is `bmpsize` bytes but the length of `pixels` is just `height` bytes - and yet you are passing it to `fread` as if it were a buffer of `bmpsize` bytes in length. Each element in `pixels` is a `char*` - the address of each is block of dynamically allocated array but this does not mean that you can treat your `pixels` array as a contiguous block of memory.

These arrays allocated dynamically in your loops are thus not initialised which could be leading to the segfaults when you read from them later in your loop (reading uninitialised variables is undefined behaviour).

This probably explains why your code works when you use a non dynamically allocated 2D array - because such a 2D array is a contiguous in memory.

Comment: but `c` should run until `width*3-3`, not `width*3-1`

Comment: I meant `c` will not be width*3-1 in the last iteration as you suggest, but width*3-3

Comment: I think you are on to something here. The way I was setting up my malloc() I wasn't getting contiguous memory, and I thing fread() requires a contiguous memory block. So I simulated my 2D Array by using a 1D Array pixels[r*height+c]. (r*height jumps me ahead to a block of the appropriate row, and the +c gets me to the right spot in that row. Unfortunately for some reason this makes the picture not change for the first 3/4 of the picture. But hey at least it's not a seg. fault now. So Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of `mathematician1975` is almost correct, since you are accessing data from outside of the area you've allocated, but the last index of `c`  in the inner loop is not `3*width-1` nor `3*width-3`, but it's actually `width*3`.

You should adapt the inner loop to:

```
for ( c = 0; c < width*3-3; c += 3)
```

This way `c` will go until `width*3-3` and then you can do `c`, `c+1` and `c+2` and you will visit the last bytes of the lines with `c+2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't think this is the issue. Imagine width was 2, then (width * 3) gives us 6 indices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
That makes out for loop (c=0; c<6; c+=3) {
so first iteration c is 0, and I access 0, 1, 2
second iteration c is 3, and I access 3, 4, 5
and the next iteration c is 6, and we exit the loop correctly.

But thanks for trying, I'm drowning here with this error. :-)